# View Network Traffic

Tags: networking, skype, ip

I've found a few programs that report network traffic, to which IPs communications are with and a few more details. Is there any way to see details of these packets? Specifically I want to view the contents of packets from and to Skype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Wireshark**](http://www.wireshark.org/) to comfortably sniff and analyze network traffic.

<sub>I do however doubt that you will be able to gain much information from Skype's proprietary protocol…</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You can use [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html), which are similar to [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), light weight and terminal only tools. But Wireshark has a nice GUI for easy understanding of the packet flow.

Comment: This is a proper answer. It would be useful if you added links in the post.

Comment: I did for him (: